# Ubuntu doesnt install any driver

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, intel-graphics, lan

the thing is simple...
I have a hp pavilion g4, i used ubuntu for some weeks and then it started to fail.
First of all, the computer started to have problems with my wifi connection.
Because of that, I reinstaled ubuntu because I thought it was because of drivers problems.

That is when all begins...
When i reinstalled ubuntu(about 5 times by now), i don't know why but I dont get the drivers( I mean lan drivers and intel graphics).

I dont know what to do now, im just getting really mad because of this..
Thanks and forgive me about my english, im hispanic.

Comment: If it was working, and now failing, sounds like a hardware problem. Hard to know from what you posted. Can you boot another OS?

Comment: Can you clarify some stuff for me please: You have what type of Intel GPU (hd2000, 3000 etc) and by "LAN" you mean the Ethernet connection on your computer for wired networking., if so what is the brand and model number. Finally, you are saying, both of these worked, then just did not one day and even after reinstalling Ubuntu they still did not work.

Comment: When I looked up your laptop it says it has Radeon HD 6480G graphics, there is no mention of Intel AT ALL the Laptop is pure AMD, is this the right one http://www.pcworld.com/product/1121308/hp-pavilion-g4-1215dx-qe133uar-notebook.html

Comment: This model is intel. There are a lot of hp pavilion g4

Comment: Hi Santiago, I'm not sure how useful the question and answer may be for further users. In any case, please don't add solutions to the question, instead add an own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Getting mad is understandable, but don't get mad at Ubuntu.  Wireless devices both internal and external, simply wear out.

I don't know if there is a particularly popular chip which is prone to failing or if the problem is caused by overheating.  In any case, there is a simply short-term fix, and that is to buy an external usb wifi adapter which is known to work with Ubuntu.  Most such devices cost under $20, and to make your quest simpler, I'm linking you to [the very model](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B07Y1D4) I carry every day in my fanny pack for emergency purposes.  It has been used in numerous repairs of ubuntu installations in which the internal wifi wasn't initially supported and it was only possible to connect the computer to the internet using this already supported device.

Later if you want your usb port back, you can have the internal wifi adapter replaced.  HPs are picky, so you have to get the exact one supported by your bios.  Don't hold me responsible if this replacement internal [HP wifi adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HLSXZ42) isn't supported by your bios, but it would probably work, and at $8, the price is right.

Comment: Solved. Reinstaled from USB. I was using a DVD before